# Generate more than one random value using Mersenne-Twister

Tags: c++

I have recently encountered a problem while generating random numbers in C++, using the `Mersenne-Twister` algorithm. When iterating through the `for` loop and using `cout` to output the generated number, it outputs the same number repeatedly. For example, it outputs something like `11 11 11` instead of `11 43 124`. How would I achieve this with code? My current code is posted below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  random_device rd;
  mt19937 gen(rd());
  uniform_int_distribution<> dis(15000, 120000);
  int random = dis(gen);

  int i = 1;
  while (i = 1) {
    cout << random << endl;
}
return 0;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to call `dis(gen)` in your loop. As written your value `random` never changes after it is assigned

Comment: `random` won't change until you reassign it

Comment: You don't get a new random number in your loop, you just print the same one over and over. Call `random = dis(gen)` again inside your while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random` is an integer object. The value of an integer object does not change unless you set its value. What you're doing here is analogous to rolling a die, writing down the random result, then repeatedly read what you wrote, expecting the written result to change.

You can generate more than one random number by applying the generator object on the distribution function more than once:

```
while (...)
    cout << dis(gen) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the command to get the random number *inside* the loop, otherwise you just print the same value over and over:

```
int i = 1;
while (i = 1) {

    int random = dis(gen); // get a new random number
    cout << random << '\n'; // print it
}
```